# Why does Ubuntu 12.04 Unity suddenly blur text and images?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, graphics

Today after a reboot, Ubuntu blurs text (well, anything that is rendered on screen) whenever focus changes or on any interactions with the desktop.

Example:

Normal good look:

[image: Standard good look]

Blurred state:

[image: Blurred state]

Note how the text, folders and the plus signs left of the folders are somewhat blurred.
In this case, the normal state is after opening the window. Blur happens on lost focus, and gets normal again whenever something is redrawn

This applies to anything that is drawn. Even in 3d games, text and thin lines flicker between normal and blurred intermittently, or whenever desktop interaction happens.

I have ruled out anything to do with font smoothing, this seems to be opengl-related.

Does not occur if I switch to Unity 2D or Gnome, but then again, that's not what I want to use.

**This just in:** As it happened, the issue fixed itself while typing this question, after Compiz crashed and restarted itself while trying to provoke the issue. Strange, seeing how the issue survived several reboots.

Comment: Hi! Do you wanna say that it fixes itself after some reboots? I hope so... I set up compiz to use cube desktop, wobbling windows and window switcher. Now I have this issue. I haven't yet tried to see what happens if I disable them, but I wanna keep them anyways...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, on a colleagues laptop. I even removed compiz (apt-get remove compiz). The bug was still apparent in unity (flickkering, appear/reappear background) no blurry screens since no text because after login nothing started: no toolbars, no icons, no menus. After an "apt-get purge compiz" and a reboot, Unity behaved normal again.

I have no idea what was true cause or solution. I didn't even need to re-install compiz or unity.